# Can't find stylesheet to import after angular upgrade

Tags: angular, sass, ng-packagr

When I run

`npx ng build @mls-ops/tests`

I have an error:

Building Angular Package

× Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
1 │ @import 'node_modules/@mls-ops/bootstrap/style/_variables.scss';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
projects\mls-ops\tests\src\lib\components\layout\table\table.component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet

Process finished with exit code 1

My library package.json

```
{
  "name": "@mls-ops/bootstrap",
  "version": "15.0.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
}
```

ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../../dist/mls-ops/bootstrap",
  "assets": [
    "/fonts/",
    "/images/",
    "/style/",
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

I have added it to my library package.json but it doesn't fix the issue.

```
 "exports": {
    "./variables": {
      "sass": "./style/_variables.scss"
    }
  }
```

Before angular migration to v15 it worked fine, help me to fix this import issue

Comment: What version of angular did you upgrade from? Shouldn't make a difference but more information rarely hurts.

Comment: Upgrade was from v14 to v15

Answer (score 0):

Import bootstrap files like this
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
This will import bootstrap.scss file.